# isEqualToString: gives out of bound exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uisearchbar

Today I received a random crash on the `isEqualToString` method used with text property of `UISearchBar`. The crash was reported on Crashlytics.

Following is the code snippet.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    if( [searchBar.text isEqualToString:@" "] )
    {
        [searchBar setText:@""];
    }
    if ( searchBar.text.length >= 2 )
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(searchForKeyword:) withObject:searchBar.text];
    }
}

-(void)searchForKeyword:(NSString *)keyword
{
    if ([keyword isEqualToString:searchBar.text])
    {
        //Search for keyword
    }
}
```

The crash says

```
Fatal Exception: `NSRangeException`
*** -[NSBigMutableString _newBigSubstringWithRange:wantsMutable:zone:]: Range {0, 4} out of bounds; string length 3
```

I have tried debugging line of code that is causing the crash but with no success. It is just randomly crashing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `keyword` can you put the whole code before the `if condition`?

Comment: @iphonic: Added the whole code

Comment: Use `performSelector` instead of `performSelectorInBackground` and check.

Comment: @Proton: No. It's a random crash. It was reported on Crashlytics only once.

Comment: @iphonic: Ok, will give it try. But do you think it would resolve the issue? Crash log says something "out of bound substringWithRange" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by that:You set the search bar text in

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

You should use the method below instead of what you use.

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(3_0); // called before text changes
```